# Is it possible to install any recent browser on an iPad 1?

Tags: ipad, web-browser

Any browser I could think of requires a version of iOS, that the iPad does not have access to.

The installed Safari browser is not able to connect to https websites.

Is there any way to display a website with modern ssl ciphers?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a proxy server that terminates the SSL with those web sites and forwards it to the old iPad in a manner it can understand.

I wouldn't recommend it, and it would be an expensive way of using an old iPad 1 if you haven't already got a proxy server lying around.